# uv mapping moving images on a mesh with dynamic distortion correction in python

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I have a series of images I want to project on to a mesh as a "movie" using a script. There is distortion that I need to compensate. I can provide a list of pixel coordinates that map to some vertices, or all vertices, or even write a transforming function if necessary ([random slightly related link](https://eserv.asprs.org/PERS/1966journal/may/1966_may_444-462.pdf)).

This list or transform is dynamic and would be calculated per animation frame. If I use a list of pixel coordinates to map to vertices, can blender shape the image smoothly in between these pinning points?

The mesh changes shape, so I need to do this algorithmically. I can not just pre-process the images offline.

How would I set this script up?

**Illustration:** Cartoonish representation of a distorted mathematical grid in the pixel space of each image to be mathematically mapped to vertices of a mesh:

[image: face grid] [image: mesh]

Comment: minimze stretch in relation to a given viewing angle?

Comment: More complicated. It doesn't have a simple physical model. Thus the awkwardly distorted grid in the cartoon.

Comment: Given an orthographic camera, is the smiley face supposed to look completely undistorted when projected on the mesh? I believe that is what the [UV project modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) is for.

Comment: Oh, that's quite cool and very good to know about! Is it still only available for internal render? In my case I'm trying to do something with an additional mathematical transform... I  will try to update the question with a more informative graphic.

Comment: It seems to work in Cycles too if you enable `Use nodes` and set the image you want to project as texture.